# Property '...' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I have a `<InputField>` component in my app with the following type definition for the props:

```
interface InputFieldProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  customProp: string;
}
```

My component looks like this:

```
const InputField: React.FC<InputFieldProps> = ({ customProp, ...htmlProps }) => {

  return (
    <input {...htmlProps} />
  );
};
```

I would expect that I can now pass the prop `disabled` or `required` to that component, as these properties are part of the HTMLInputElement type definition. However, I get the error:

> Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'

I tried passing disabled as `disabled={true}` as well as just `disabled` with no success. I can, however, pass `placeholder` as a prop. So some properties in the HTMLInputElement type definition seem to work, while others don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>` is right. Just make sure any additional property, such as `customProp`, does not reach your `input`. In the below example, because `customProp` is destructed on its own, `inputProps` would include only `input` properties.

```
interface InputFieldProps extends React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  customProp: string;
}

const InputField: React.FC<InputFieldProps> = ({
  customProp,
  ...inputProps
}) => {
  return <input {...inputProps} />;
};
```

[image: Edit angry-fast-upe615]